# How to simplify a multiline geometry in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, generalization

I'm trying to simplify my shapefile, which uses a lot of vertices to represent curvatures, by using the Generalizer plugin. But no matter what threshold I use for Douglas algorithm, it still includes almost all of those closely placed vertices, which I can see are less than 1 feet away from each other. Any hints of what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Can you share a data sample to test?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28390827/sample%20shp/sample%20shp.rar

Comment: @Pep do you solve this problem?

Comment: @GLeBaTi check underdark's answer. I ended up manually joining all the short links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing the algorithm could simplify. In the test data you provided, one road/curve is modeled using multiple very short links which - by themselves - are mostly just short straight lines.

Comment: My bad; didn't expect it to be like that. Do you know any methods to merge those tiny links together automatically? I was thinking of doing it based on node degree(much like the second answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735252/remove-all-nodes-in-a-networkx-digraph-with-in-degree-and-out-degree-equal-to-1), but it messed up a lot of other features

Comment: Best ask the merge question separately. It requires topology-aware tools. I currently can't think of a good solution off the top of my head.